# Fail to display the context passed to templates while using Django3.1

Tags: python, django, django-3.1

I want to use Django to make a notice board on my website, so I made a model like this:

```
class notice(models.Model):
    # the title of the notice
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

And I wrote "views.py" like this (the main part):

```
def notices(request):
    # display the notice title
    notices = notice.objects.order_by("date_added")
    context = {"notice": notices}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

But in the file "index.html", when I wrote these codes:

```
    <ul>
        {% for n in notices %}
        <li>{{n.text}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Nothing was displayed.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I'd be grateful if you help me.

Well...My English is really poor, and if what I said is kind of impolite... Might you just forgive me for that? Thanks!

### Update:

Thanks for Biplove Lamichhane's answer! And This is what it said while running the Django Shell:

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from wl.models import *
>>> notice.objects.order_by("date_added")
<QuerySet [<notice: testing>]>
```

In "index.html":

```
    <ul>
        {% for n in notices %}
        <li>{{n}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

In "views.py":

```
def notices(request):
    # display the notice title
    notices = notice.objects.order_by("date_added")
    context = {"notices": notices}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Still, displayed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You gave `notice` to the context variable, here: `context = {"notice": notices}`. But used, `notices` in template. So, either change the variable in views.py like:

```
context = {"notices": notices}
```

Or,

Change template like:

```
    <ul>
        {% for n in notice %}
        <li>{{ n.text }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

### Update

As your notice class `__str__` returns `text` you can simply do:

```
<li>{{ n }}</li>
```

Comment: So, you added `s` to the context variable in views.py right?

Comment: Can you make sure your queryset actually have value by printing on console??

Comment: I updated the question, added the query set displayed in the Django Shell

Comment: Okay... seems like there is data... Should have work... Can you edit your post again with the changes you have made after I wrote this answer to make sure that you did it correctly.

Comment: Let's try this tomorrowI have to do something else now, thanks for answering

Comment: I'm back now, and I edited the post with the changes

Comment: It seems fine... You have to check urls if you are editing one thing and checking on another.

Answer (score 1):

yes indeed it's a typo. make it notice in the html page, you're done.

Comment: But it's strangely uselessI don't know why either